# In TortoiseSVN, can I preview the specific changes of a test merge?

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn, diff

TortoiseSVN's test merge feature shows me a list of all files that would be changed by a merge, and whether the change is an update, merge, conflict needing resolution, etc.

But I can't figure out a way to see the diff so I know *exactly* how the merged-into area (in my case, the project trunk) will be changed. Can this be done? Merely seeing the diff doesn't feel adequate, because I want to know how the program will decide to resolve those diffs in each case.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the regular merge and check your working copy. Just don't commit the result of the merge before you are sure it's the one you expect or want.

Don't forget to use up-to-date TortoiseSVN 1.9 client.